# hdfview | tree structure doesn't show up

Tags: ubuntu, hdf5, kde-plasma

I just installed hdfview through the ubuntu repositories with the apt package-manager. I can open hdfview and load a .hdf5 file, but if I click on the file the tree structure doesn't show up.

When I start hdfview through the terminal I get the warning message:
`[warning] /usr/bin/hdfview: JVM flavor 'sun' not understood`

I'm using KDE neon.

Does someone know a solution for this?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS/application support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [unix.se] instead. Note that KDE Neon is based on Ubuntu, but not an official flavour, so [ubuntu.se] doesn't cover it.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for pointing out! I got it by now. The version in the ubuntu-repositories is extremly outdated. `https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/installing-hdfview-on-linux/7817` helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repost my comment on my question. To be able to close this question.

> @wjandrea Thanks for pointing out! I got it by now. The version in the
> ubuntu-repositories is extremly outdated.
> https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/installing-hdfview-on-linux/7817 helped.  –
> 123
> Dec 9, 2021 at 21:46